# Is there a way to use rc-Files for VisualStudioCode?

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, winapi, rc

I try to use this tutotial for winapi-programming: http://www.winprog.org/tutorial/resources.html it works fine until i have to use rc-files which seem to not work in visualstudio code. is anyone out there who can help me or give me a guess how to workaround this problem?

I debugged the tutorial but the program does not work like it should. with a visualstudio2022 community license it does work. the usage of vs2022 is unfortunately no option

Comment: Many project build-tools like CMake and Meson, and probably others, handle it for you. Then you just configure the `tasks.json` file to run the generated build-system and it will be built and linked. You can of course create the build-system files yourself, like for the `make` or `nmake` programs, and tell them to build the resource files.

Comment: If you want to build for windows I would suggest VisualStudio without the "Code"

Comment: Visual Studio Code is just a fancy text editor, it does not "handle" resource files at all. That is done by the tools that Visual Studio ships with. Visual Studio simply handles the setup for you, VSCode does no such thing for any language

Comment: thx for the quick response. I have a look at your tips

Comment: _"visualstudio2022 community license it does work_": what does not work? It should work. Maybe you should ask a question about this.

Comment: To turn a resource script into an object file you can pass to the linker, you need the [resource compiler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/resource-compiler). It comes with Visual Studio or the Windows SDK. If Visual Studio is not an option, you need the Windows SDK.